# Magento 2 site upgrade pending or patches

Tags: magento2, patches, magento-upgrade, wordpress

I have a magento2 website on which i need to check if there is any upgrade pending or patches ,
how would i know about it , or how can i check it ?

It has also fishpig wp module to connect wp
so i to check available upgrade for wp as well , how one can do it ?

Comment: Thankyou for the answers, is their any way we can check if  site/magento need security patch ?

Answer (score 0):

Just go through this guide: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

I hope you might get the answer of your query and other related questions around Magento update, patches and a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

Magento use composer for dependency management

So, you need run `composer outdated magento\*` from cli to see if there are packages that can be updated